# Slang word for transferring money from one card to another

Tags: american-english, british-english, speech

Ok, so there is an Online Money Transfer Service. It allows for quick money transfer from one card to another. The advertisement of this service describes how it is convenient for parents to transfer money to their's children card in a very short time.

Now, is there a Slang word for "transferring money" in the context of parents transferring money from their card to their children's card? This slang word should be much less formal.

For example in Russian "transferring money from one card to another" could use a slang word and it would sound something like "*throw* money from one card to another".

P.S. "Send" money is the simple option that comes to my mind. Any other ideas?

Comment: *Move* money from one card to another may be another  option.

Comment: *Inject money into (something)* is another  idiomatic expression, but it is generally used referring to a company, a bank or the economy, not a card!!

Comment: "Keep money on your own card and tell your kid to get a job!"

Comment: Ian nailed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Load (money  to) your card** is  an informal expression and a useful alternative to *transfer*.

> - Prepaid cards let you load cash on them and spend anywhere credit or debit cards are accepted.

Comment: MoneyGram thing :)